# Can anyone translate this Seal Script into english for me?

Tags: translation, characters, character-identification, seal, hong-kong

I played this game called Sleeping Dogs that I really loved! It took place in Hong Kong and the main character Wei Shen has this tattoo on his arm that I thought would be cool to have. After doing some research I was told this was Seal Script and was not commonly used among the Chinese people. I would like some help deciphering this please and thank you!

Tattoo worn by Wei Shen in Sleeping Dogs

[image: one]

A picture of a cosplayer as well as another tattoo the character has which may add some context

[image: two]

[image: three]

Comment: Errmm..maybe someone who has played the game would have better insight. From the characters I could decipher, I haven't been able to make a coherent phrase yet...

Comment: @droooze, come on, you can; read vertically :)

Comment: @MiguelBailon Is this the actual tattoo on his arm? Or is this some fan-art imitation?

Comment: This was pulled from the official website thats no longer there due too the game developers going out of business. I might add screenshots of his arm to the question, thanks for trying :). (By the way, the woman in the middle is his sister who passed away, maybe that will help?)

Comment: @MiguelBailon ah okay. If I may venture a guess (before I see the tattoo on his arm): these characters are just for artistic flair, and don't actually say anything. Even from the characters identified, I can't find a coherent phrase that suggests the tattoo is saying something meaningful.

Comment: Ah thanks so much for the help!

Comment: This is not a cosplayer. This is a stuntman, Brian Ho, who played Wei in the live trailer for the game

Answer (score 1):

Draft decipherment:

> 告`鹿`右Ｘ各　ＸＸＸ以`金`
>
> 瓜孔豕Ｘ亞　受Ｘ止而弟
>
> `豆`Ｘ月`勒`子　Ｘ水東君`者`

- Uncertain characters

Ｘ - can't read

---

[image]

---

Neither of the tattoos say something legible, in my opinion. The characters are for artistic flair.

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 I don't think this text says anything....looks like nonsense

Comment: i agreed with your finding, and, can't grep any meaning from it :(

Comment: Tragic, thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

at frist glance, the right part:

```
ｘｘｘｘｘ
ｘｘ之ｘ弟
ｘ水東君ｘ
```

i'm watching movie at this moment, would decipher the rest later:)